Error creating Oracle trigger for audit logs of table changes
I'm attempting to create a trigger in Oracle to maintain a log of changes in a specific table. My goal is to record inserts, updates, and deletes in the CLIENTS table into an audit table called CLIENTS_LOG. However, when trying to create the trigger, I encounter errors related to the NEW and OLD bind variables. It seems like the link variable is wrong.
Here's the trigger code I'm using:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CLIENTS_LOG_TRIGGER
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON CLIENTS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    V_OLD_NAME VARCHAR2(100);
    V_OLD_LASTNAME VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
        INSERT INTO CLIENTS_LOG (AUDIT_ID, CLIENT_ID, NEW_NAME, NEW_LASTNAME, MODIFICATION_DATE, MODIFYING_USER)
        VALUES (AUDIT_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :NEW.CLIENT_ID, :NEW.NAME, :NEW.LASTNAME, SYSTIMESTAMP, USER);
    ELSIF UPDATING THEN
        SELECT NAME, LASTNAME INTO V_OLD_NAME, V_OLD_LASTNAME FROM CLIENTS WHERE CLIENT_ID = :OLD.CLIENT_ID;
        INSERT INTO CLIENTS_LOG (AUDIT_ID, CLIENT_ID, OLD_NAME, NEW_NAME, OLD_LASTNAME, NEW_LASTNAME, MODIFICATION_DATE, MODIFYING_USER)
        VALUES (AUDIT_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :OLD.CLIENT_ID, V_OLD_NAME, :NEW.NAME, V_OLD_LASTNAME, :NEW.LASTNAME, SYSTIMESTAMP, USER);
    ELSIF DELETING THEN
        INSERT INTO CLIENTS_LOG (AUDIT_ID, CLIENT_ID, OLD_NAME, OLD_LASTNAME, MODIFICATION_DATE, MODIFYING_USER)
        VALUES (AUDIT_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :OLD.CLIENT_ID, :OLD.NAME, :OLD.LASTNAME, SYSTIMESTAMP, USER);
    END IF;
END;

Also, here are the tables:
-- Table structure for CLIENTS
CREATE TABLE CLIENTS (
    CLIENT_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR2(100),
    LASTNAME VARCHAR2(100)
);

-- Table structure for CLIENTS_LOG
CREATE TABLE CLIENTS_LOG (
    AUDIT_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    CLIENT_ID NUMBER,
    OLD_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
    NEW_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
    OLD_LASTNAME VARCHAR2(100),
    NEW_LASTNAME VARCHAR2(100),
    MODIFICATION_DATE TIMESTAMP,
    MODIFYING_USER VARCHAR2(100)
);

I have tried to change the log table or modify the :OLD and :NEW clauses but i keep running into the same problem.

You have this inside your trigger:
SELECT NAME, LASTNAME INTO V_OLD_NAME, V_OLD_LASTNAME 
  FROM CLIENTS WHERE CLIENT_ID = :OLD.CLIENT_ID;

You cannot select from the base table that is being modified or you'll get a mutating error. Instead, simply use the :OLD pseudorow to reference old values. For updates, you have both :OLD and :NEW and you can mix up references to them at will:
INSERT INTO CLIENTS_LOG (AUDIT_ID, CLIENT_ID, OLD_NAME, NEW_NAME, OLD_LASTNAME, NEW_LASTNAME, MODIFICATION_DATE, MODIFYING_USER)
        VALUES (2, :OLD.CLIENT_ID, :OLD.NAME, :NEW.NAME, :OLD.LASTNAME, :NEW.LASTNAME, SYSTIMESTAMP, USER);

Also be sure your AUDIT_SEQ sequence already exists. That's the only thing that would cause a compilation error. The mutating error would happen when you tried to do an update of the base table, not at compilation time.

If you'd prefer to not build your own, I've got a tool that will take a table name and generate audit tables and triggers for you.
https://github.com/connormcd/audit_utility
Alternatively, check out Flashback Data Archive (now called Time Travel) which can serve as a very efficient audit solution because no triggers are required
